# Wie ist das Wort "Antibabypille" entstanden?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

Das Wort *Antibabypille* ist im Vergleich zu den Bezeichnungen in anderen Sprachen merkwürdig explizit, man könnte es unsachlich nennen, indem es von Babys und nicht von Empfängnisverhütung oder von Schwangerschaft spricht.

Zum Vergleich:

> Englisch: birth control pill
> Französisch: la pilule contraceptive
> Spanisch: píldora anticonceptiva
> Polnisch: pigułka antykoncepcyjna
> Chinesisch: 避孕片 bìyùnpiàn (vermeiden schwanger Tablette)

Weiß jemand, wie es im Deutschen dazu kam? War das Wort eine Bezeichnung aus dem Marketing der Hersteller? Aus der Ablehnung in der gesellschaftlichen Debatte?

Mir kommen z.B. die "Bild" und andere Medien als Schöpfer ähnlich ausdrucksstarker und einprägsamer Worterfindungen in den Sinn, aber ich frage mich dann, wie ein (zumindest aus meiner Sicht) sehr mit Meinung aufgeladener Begriff aus einem Medium so allgemein angenommen werden konnte.

Der [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibabypille#Bezeichnung) sagt nur, dass sich das Wort schnell durchsetzte.

Inspiration für die Frage: [Youtube short: "When Germans name their things"](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/yyvnfHJ26aA)

Comment: In der DDR prägte man den Begriff "Wunschkindpille". Der ist noch mehr explizit. Aber ist das nicht eine Eigenschaft der deutschen Sprache, das alles was nicht brutal direkt ist, als Euphemismus aufgefasst wird?

Comment: Ich finde das Thema interessant, muß aber sagen: 1. Die Frage *wie kann ein so mit Meinung aufgeladener Begriff aus einem Medium dann so allgemein angenommen werden?* wird sehr schwer objektiv zu beantworten sein. 2. Begriffsgeschichte ist bei den Historikern besser aufgehoben.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Ja, stimmt, das war auch eigentlich nicht so sehr als Teil der Frage gedacht, sondern nur als Überlegung zu Wahrscheinlichkeiten. Mich interessiert in erster Linie, ob die Quelle dieser Wortschöpfung bekannt ist. Wenn man was dazu weiß, warum er sich so verbreitet hat, ist das nur ein Plus.

Comment: Ich finde den Namen sehr naheliegend. Es beschreibt genau das, was man nicht haben möchte: ein Baby. Anfangs wurde die Pille als Hilfe gegen Menstruationsbeschwerden beworben und Verhütung war nur als Nebenwirkung angegeben.

Comment: Als zusätzlicher Aspekt: der Überbegriff lautet sehr wohl "Empfängnisverhütung" (Kontrazeption), was den angeführten anderssprachigen Ausdrücken (Ausnahme: Englisch) entspricht und auch genauer ist, weil ja primär nicht das Gebären bzw. das Kind, sondern die Empfängnis desselben verhindert wird.

Comment: @bakunin Empfängnis und Baby liegen neun Monate auseinander. Davon drei Monate, in denen unter Umständen sogar noch legal abgetrieben werden könnte. Für mich klingt "Antibabypille" nach der Erfindung von jemandem, der die Empfängnisverhütung absichtlich von vorneherein mit einer Abtreibung in die gleiche Schublade stecken wollte, wie es die katholische Sexuallehre tut (nach der Sex nur erlaubt ist, wenn man die Erzeugung von Nachwuchs zumindest in Kauf nimmt, und die deshalb Verhütung nicht erlaubt). U.a. deshalb interessiert mich, ob die Entstehungsgeschichte bekannt ist.

Comment: @HalvarF: mir sind die grundsätzlichen Mechanismen menschlicher Vermehrung andeutungsweise bekannt und davon, daß eine Schwangerschaft neun Monate dauert, habe ich auch schon gerüchteweise gehört. Ich wollte lediglich einen zusätzlichen Aspekt einbringen, *eben weil* das Wort "Anti-Baby-Pille" bei näherer Betrachtung sonderbar wirkt. Daß dahinter womöglich eine Sexualmoral aus der Bronzezeit steht, erscheint mir in einem Land, das das Tanzen am Karfreitag gesetzlich verbietet, durchaus plausibel.

Comment: Eva-Maria Sillies: Liebe, Lust und Last. Die Pille als weibliche Generationserfahrung in der Bundesrepublik 1960-1980, Göttingen 2010: Wallstein Verlag diskutiert das anscheinend auf S. 97f. Unglücklicher Weise enthält [Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=3gl4DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q&f=false) in der freien Voransicht nur S.98, mit einer unvollständigen Fußnote, die auf einen Artikel in der Zeitschrift "Für Sie" von 1979 verweist – anscheinend war der Wortursprung dort auf die Verwendung durch Reporter zurückgeführt worden.

Comment: @ccprog Danke, sehr interessant, das hat mich dann zu dieser Arbeit von 1989 geführt: https://bibliothek.wzb.eu/pdf/1989/p89-204.pdf Darin wird auf die Frage leider nicht explizit eingegangen, aber es wird auf Seiten 45ff. ein Artikel im Stern von 1963 erwäht, der schon die Überschrift "Die Anti-Baby-Pille" hatte, während im ersten Artikel über das Thema im Stern 1961 noch allgemein von "der Pille" und der "Pincus-Pille" die Rede war.

Comment: Auch erwähnt ist, dass der CDU-Inneminister 1964 die Bezeichnung "Anti-Baby-Pille", die in Presseberichten verwendet werde, "grob anstößig" nannte. Es scheint nicht so bekannt zu sein, wie ich gehofft hatte, wie die Bezeichnung entstanden ist, und das Thema dürfte für German Language SE wohl doch eine Überforderung sein.

Comment: Ich finde das Wort aussagekräftig. Das ist ähnlich wie "Antihaftbelag" (ein Belag, damit ein Gegenstand nicht haftet, dass also kein Anhaften stattifindet). Antibabypille ist also eine Pille, die dafür sorgt, dass kein Baby kommt. Wesentlich unlogischer ist, dass in der Praxis die Leute nicht "Antibabypille" sagen, sondern nur "Pille".

Comment: @user1934428 Dass das Wort nicht *aussagekräftig* wäre, hat nun wirklich niemand behauptet. :-)